# Download URL history of IE9 and IE10

Tags: c++, internet-explorer

I want to know where does the Internet Explorer stores the history for the downloads (urls).
Does it keep it in some DB files like Firefox and Chrome? Or does it store it in Registry?

Comment: Have you tried searching for this elsewhere?

Comment: yes..obviously. Stackoverflow is my last option

Comment: ...how about in your own computer?

Comment: Yes.. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs` this stores the history for last typed url..but couldnt find download url history

Comment: Thanks - would you mind editing in why you tagged this with C++ also?

Comment: because people may suggest me some other language libraries which wont be of much use to me.

Comment: Your original question didn't ask for anything to do with programming, just the location - that's why I asked you to clarify. If you can, let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33319/discussion-between-icedwater-and-smilepleeeaz)

Comment: waiting for you in chat.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the term "Downloads" is a bit ambiguous-- do you mean "File downloads" or "All content downloaded by the browser including images, CSS, JS, etc)?

Internet Explorer stores virtually all of its records in databases (IE9 and below use memory-mapped files named index.dat, while IE10+ use a proper database engine).

You should not attempt to manually interact with index.dat or the database; instead, you should use the appropriate APIs (e.g. the WinINET cache APIs or the IE History APIs) to collect data as needed.

Comment: Hi @EricLaw Thanks for your response. By download here I mean the file downloads only. I want to get the list of the urls of the downloaded files. I have solved it for up to IE8 which as you said is in index.dat but for IE 9 & 10 I think Microsoft has used some other mechanism. May be in `C:\Users\[User Profile]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\` Can you pls point me to link of the APIs you mentioned ?

Comment: IE9 also uses Index.dat (discussed here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2006/08/04/wininet-index-dat.aspx); while IE10 uses a database as its index instead. You can learn more about WinINET's cache enumeration functions on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384034(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I am concerned with ie10, where is the index database of ie10 located ?